# Problemas con WebpackDevServer en React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Intentaba configurar mi propio proyecto de *React*, pero me encuentro con el problema que cuando uso *WebpackDevServer*, todo bien, el servidor se monta, pero cuando modifico el código de un *component* de *React* el servidor debería compilar dicho archivo, y en consola muestra que efectivamente lo hizo pero realmente no lo hace, entonces debo estar constantemente compilando el proyecto entero con *WebPack **build*** lo cual es más lento.

Capturas de mi **webpack.config**:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode:'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCSSExtractPlugin({
            filename: "styles.css"
        })
      ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000",
        liveReload: true,
        hotOnly: true
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          loader: [
              MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
              'css-loader',
            ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/i,
          loader: [
              MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ]
        },
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando la siguiente configuración del devServer al fichero webpack.config

```
devServer: {
            port: 3000,
            allowedHosts: ["0.0.0.0"],
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
            },
            hot: true,
            compress: true,
            disableHostCheck: true,
            overlay: true
        }
```